# Can't find web project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I simply can't find new Web Application Project or Web Project when I click New->Project in Eclipse. Any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed the necessary plugins for web development in eclipse?

Comment: can you tell me how to do that??

Comment: I am not sure how familiar you are with Eclipse but [this link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#plugin_installation) will show you how to find and install plugins.  Try looking for any packages that have to do with the languages you will be using in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean New->Other->Web->( Dynamic Web application or Static Web Application etc. ). I am using a Java EE Eclipse Helios version.

Comment: Yes, I can't find it... I am using Eclipse helios 3.6

Comment: You need the WTP if not already installed.... here "The Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) software repository - http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/helios" add this to install new software urls

Comment: I have the same problem, spent hours trying to work out how to get WTP into elcipse java edition (Juno).  There is nothing under marketplace or "Install new software" using the juno repo (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno) .  Anyone know how to isntall WTP, or the URL of a repo which has it?

Comment: @wingnut Help -> Install New Software -> Add -> Location paste http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/juno

Comment: Nice, that works!  Thanks.  Shame its not in the default locations.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/eclipse/).

Comment: I have downloaded the Google Plugin for Eclipse but still I am not able to get Dynamic Web Project.. do you have any idea if there are any other plugins that I am missing?